# About three-point method

Tags: numerical-methods

Using the three-point startpoint formula to find $f^{'}(7.4)$ where:
$f(7.4)=-68.3193, f(7.6)=-71.6982, f(7.8)=-75.1576$

I got the approximated value: $f^{'}(7.4)=-16.69325$

then the actual error equals: $0.000367$ where $f(x)=ln(x+2)-(x+1)^{2}$

and the error bound equals: $0.000032$ where the error bound has the formula: $EB=max|(h^{2}/3)(f^{'''}(x)|$

My question is, how can the value of error BOUND is less than the value of actual error!.. I understood that the error bound has the greater value of the error may occure using this method of approximation.

Comment: maybe it should be $EB=max|(h^{2}/2)(f^{''}(x)|$

Comment: No, actually it is the third derivative function!

Comment: Then it should be $EB=max|(h^{2}/3!)(f^{'''}(x)|$.

Comment: Which derivative are you calculating?

Comment: It comes from the differentiating the Lagrange interpolating error bound, and I found it in a book

Comment: the third one: $f^{'''}(x)=2/(x+2)^{3}$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here the law I have found in the book!

Comment: ah ok it's a not centered method

Comment: what do you mean by centered method please?

Comment: "not centered"in the sense that you calculate the value of f'(x) at the left point $x_0$

Comment: yes, by the startpoint formula, using $7.4, 7.6, 7.8$ what is the mistake?

Comment: I really don't know, I obtain the same results!

Comment: OK thanks :( 
can anyone help please!!!

Comment: Let's try with a shorter interval step h.

Comment: Finally I got the answer of my question :)

The actual error is greater than the error bound because the accuracy of the error bound is greater than the accuracy of the data which are given in the original question! you can notice that the numbers in the question are with 4 decimals only!. I tried to solve with data with 9 decimals then I got more accurate answers so that the actual error is less than the error bound :)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well done! Thanks for the update.!